# How to connect my counter to my flask web page

Tags: python, html, flask

I am making a website and I the website has a scraper that scrapes another website. On my website I want to have this counter (that shows which page is currently being scraper, so that the user knows everything is running smooth)

```
#---------------------------------------------- scarper.py

# ... rest of the code

counter = 0

while True:
    counter += 1
    print(f'Extracting infromation from page: {counter}')

#... rest of the code
```

to be shown on my website (instead of console log) in between these two buttons. How can I achieve this?

```
#---------------------------------------------- scrape.html

#... rest of the code

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Start Scraping</button>
<a href="{{ url_for('view_database') }}" class="btn btn-info">View Database</a>

#... rest of the code
```

The code for the route and its function is the following:

```
@app.route('/scrape', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def scrape():
    form = ScrapingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        city = request.form.get('city')
        subregion = request.form.get('subregion')
        apart_or_house = request.form.get('apart_or_house')
        words_to_check = request.form.get('words_to_check')  # Retrieve words to check input

        if city and apart_or_house:
            g.scraping_finished = False
            threading.Thread(target=run_scraper, args=(city, subregion, apart_or_house, words_to_check)).start() 
            flash('Scraping started!', 'success')
        else:
            flash('Please fill all required fields.', 'error')

    if g.get('scraping_finished', False):
        flash('Scraper has finished!', 'info')

    return render_template('scrape.html', form=form)


@app.route('/scraping-finished')
def scraping_finished():
    return render_template('scraping_finished.html')


def run_scraper(city, subregion, apart_or_house, words_to_check):
    # Ask the user for input
    base_url = ""
    while True:
        if city != "":
            break
        else:
            flash("City name cannot be empty. Please enter a valid city name.", "error")
            return

    while True:
        if apart_or_house == "wohnung" or apart_or_house == 'haus':
            break
        elif apart_or_house == "":
            flash("This field cannot be empty. Please enter what are you buying.", "error")
        else:
            flash("Please enter either 'wohnung' or 'haus'.", "error")
            return

    if subregion:
        base_url = f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/{city}/{city}/{subregion}/{apart_or_house}-kaufen"
    else:
        base_url = f"https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/{city}/{city}/{apart_or_house}-kaufen"

    # Run the scraper script with the provided inputs and base_url
    subprocess.run(['python', 'scraper.py', city, subregion, apart_or_house, base_url, words_to_check])

    with current_app.test_request_context():
        return redirect(url_for('scraping_finished'))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is with SSR and creating an event on the client.

Add an element to display the counter value in your scrape.html:

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Start Scraping</button>
    <span id="counter">0</span>
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-info">View Database</a>

    <script>
        var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('scrape') }}");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    </script>
```

Change your scrape.py to:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your-secret-key-for-csrf'


class ScrapingForm(FlaskForm):
    city = StringField('City', validators=[DataRequired()])
    subregion = StringField('Subregion')
    apart_or_house = SelectField('Apartment or House', choices=[('apartment', 'Apartment'), ('house', 'House')],
                                 validators=[DataRequired()])
    words_to_check = StringField('Words to Check')
    submit = SubmitField('Start Scraping')


def run_scraper(city, subregion, apart_or_house, words_to_check):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        counter += 1
        print(f'Extracting information from page: {counter}')
        yield f'data: {counter}\n\n'


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def scrape():
    form = ScrapingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        city = request.form.get('city')
        subregion = request.form.get('subregion')
        apart_or_house = request.form.get('apart_or_house')
        words_to_check = request.form.get('words_to_check')

        if city and apart_or_house:
            return Response(stream_with_context(run_scraper(city, subregion, apart_or_house, words_to_check)),
                            mimetype='text/event-stream')
        else:
            flash('Please fill all required fields.', 'error')

    return render_template('scrape.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I also replaced the thread with stream_with_context, and removed the `g`.
The counter value is updated on `document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = event.data`.

Comment: I have uploaded my code  (the scrape route, the function run_scraper). Can you implemted that login into my existing code and edit your answer? Thank you upfront.

Answer (score 0):

On your html:
`Counter value: <div id="counter"></div>`

On your js file:

```
function updateCounter() {
            fetch('/get_counter').then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById('counter').innerText = data.count;
                });
        }
        setInterval(updateCounter, 1000);#time the updates as needed
```

On your flask backend:

```
@app.route('/get_counter')
def get_count():
    counter = #your logic for getting the counter count running on backend
    return jsonify({'count': counter})
```

You can use ajax for this ,however it will be a constant stream of packets for no reason. A better approach would be running it on JS on client side or using a button to retrive it from server as and when needed.

Comment: I don't have a JS file. I only have python and html files.

Comment: You don't need a seperate file , you can just put it in a `<script>//js code here </script>` element at the end just before `</body>` tag

Comment: Okey, but what should I enter in the function get_count for the counter where you have putted to enter my own logic? In my scraper.py I just initialized it to be 0 and to rise by one on each new page.